# How can I place multiple QToolButton one after the other, instead of being one below the other

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbutton

I am working on a QT project that makes it possible to view and edit table views from a given file.
For the buttons in the GUI I'm using QToolButton, but when more than one button is created, they are placed one below the other, whereas I would like them all to be shown one after the other on the same row. Here is the code for the two buttons:

```
QToolButton* newFileButton = new QToolButton(this);  
newFileButton -> setIcon(QIcon(":/images/newFile.svg"));
newFileButton -> setIconSize(QSize(44, 44));
newFileButton -> setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
newFileButton -> setText("New File");

QToolButton* openFileButton = new QToolButton(this);
openFileButton -> setIcon(QIcon(":/images/openFile.svg"));
openFileButton -> setIconSize(QSize(44, 44));
openFileButton -> setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
openFileButton -> setText("Open");
```

This is what I get:

[image: The buttons are positioned one below the other]

How can I place them one after the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a horizontal layout or a widget with horizontal layout. You can also use a grid layout for your window and make the table span all columns.

There is also the QButtonBox that has a number of default buttons with default icons that might mesh better with the users theme.